# Address is not valid for this content error when building solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opencv

Getting the following error when building solution in `Visual Studio`:

> Unable to start program C:\Users\me\Desktop\gesture\SignsLanguageRecognition_using_qt\src\debug\untitled.exe The address is not valid for this content.

Comment: Read the message and change the Output Directory setting as it suggests.

Comment: i got dt ...please help with adress not valid for this content error...!!

Comment: Please review [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35952829/revisions) before editing this question again - you're reverting good edits made by other people.